# How to bind a variable at the start of URL on cURL, it is throwing error

Tags: linux, bash, shell, curl, sh

```
curl \ -H "Content-Type: application/json" \ -X POST \ $REPOSITORY_URL/engine-rest
```

`http://10.195.177.141:31406` is bound to `REPOSITORY_URL`.

```
curl: no URL specified! curl: try 'curl --help' or 'curl --manual' for more information
```

I tried giving double quotes as well

Comment: What are those backslashes? Also, are you sure that's exactly what's in the variable (no invisible characters or anything like that)? Try `set -x` before this, so you can see what bash thinks is happening.

Comment: You should provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Also see [How to use Shellcheck](http://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck), [How to debug a bash script?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/155551/56041) (U&L.SE), [How to debug a bash script?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/951336/608639) (SO), [How to debug bash script?](http://askubuntu.com/q/21136) (AskU), [Debugging Bash scripts](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_02_03.html), etc.

Answer (score 0):

TL;DR:  Remove `\` and try again.

Try this:

```
curl  -H "Content-Type: application/json"  -X POST  $REPOSITORY_URL/engine-rest
```

To me, it appears as if the `\` characters in the command line are superfluous.  They are telling bash to treat the space as part of the parameter  value instead of a separator.  With that in mind, the first argument you are passing to curl is " -H" (that is, :space:-H).  Since this argument doesn't start with a `-`, the program assumes that it is the URL.  curl performs a DNS lookup on `-H` and cannot resolve that host name:

```
curl: (6) Could not resolve host:  -H
```

I suspect the reason why I have a different error than you is because I am using curl on MacOS.

Comment: even i am running curl on mac, when i give the direct url without binding , it works fine.Only when i give binding variable in uri, it doesn't.

Comment: And also when i echo it after binding, i could see proper uri but curl is throwing error.

Comment: Have you removed the `\\`?